# How can I connect my 2017 Macbook Pro to Apple Airport Extreme via ethernet?

Tags: networking, macos, router, mac, ethernet

I want to maximize my upload/download speeds by using ethernet in my Apple Airport Extreme.  I purchased a ethernet cable and an ethernet -> usb-c.  I plugged it into the Airport Extreme but I can't figure out how to configure the network preferences.

[image]

Which one do I choose from this? and what do I do next?

I have a modem that I plug my Airport into. I want to directly plug my computer into the Apple Airport and bypass WIFI.

Comment: Please update the question with the make/model of the USB ethernet adapter.  Have you tried Disabling wireless temporarily?  Have you tried plugging into other Ethernet devices?  Have you tried swapping USB ports?  Confirmed the Ethernet cable works for other devices?

Comment: What did you try so far & what were your results? en1 would be the obvious one to try first.

Comment: One thing you'll likely run into is the ordering of the interfaces.  You may need to adjust the service order.  You can do that by clicking the Gear Icon at the bottom of the service list and drag your interface you prefer to the top.